# IPhone SDK file transfer resume support

Tags: iphone, resume, transfer

I am trying to save voice recordings and transfer those files to my FTP server, typically ranging from 200kb up to 75 MB in size. I anticipate infrequent mid-session internet disconnections or app being terminated or the user inadvertently pressing the home button.  Just wondering how to set up resume of transfers without having to start afresh, as this would be a pain, particularly when transferring large files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FTP client will need to send a [`REST`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands) (`RESTart`) command, with an offset for where the transfer last ended.